# "Python extension loading" Issue inside VS Code attached containers

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

When trying to attach to a docker container using VS Code and execute python code in a Jupyter notebook file, the python extension gave me "python extension loading" and it also failed to run any python code. I did however find a fix by turning off telemetry but then that started to causes excessive CPU usage (100%). The chrome Jupyter notebook works fine, however, an IDE like VS Code would help a lot. If anybody has a fix for this please let me know. Thanks!

VS Code extensions enabled: Python, Pylance, Docker, Jupyter       <- ALL made by Microsoft